# Twilio Programmable Chat User Channel Limit - best practice?

Tags: twilio, chat, limit

We are using Twilio Programmable Chat in our product and we're running into the issue of having too many channels per user. (Every once in a while, I increase the limit in our app, but there is an absolute maximum of 1,000) so we're going to hit that limit in a few months I beliee

I'm wondering if there are any best practices to manage this? SHould we remove the user from a channel after a period of time? What happens if the user wants to participate in the channel again in the future? If we re-add the user to the channel, will the profile be linked? (assuming our unique identifier for the user is the same?)

Unfortunately, I was unable to find specifics about this in the help documentation - so apologies if it does exist!

Thanks very much!
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio's suggestion here is to add/remove users from/to channels on demand, for example when new message is posted to the channel. They could use Chat webhooks to handle new message events (onMessageSent) and add the user back.